# why does my android show -67 on my email icon?

Tags: email, home-screen-shortcuts

On the home screen, my Samsung Galaxy, it shows -67 over the email icon. What is this indicating and more importantly, how can I get rid of it?

Comment: Please provide a screenshot

Answer (score 1):

It's buggy.  You should be able to fix it by clearing the data for the email app and/or any related apps (sometimes there's an "Email Storage" app and so on).

Answer (score 0):

This may be count of new emails in your mailbox.
There is a functionality that shows count on icons for Email Messages etc.

Some launchers are implemented it ,and most of the new custiom ROMs also.

BTW please provide a screenshot for more accurate answer.